# Angular signals - sibling component does not update when using signal.update unless the object reference is broken

Tags: angular

I am wondering what is the point of using signal.update if changes do not trigger change detection in all components that either using effect or call the signal in the views?

Here is a simple case in which I have two sibling components child1 and child2.

```
<app-child1></app-child1>
<app-child2></app-child2>
```

Child1 calls update and simply just updates the object's properties. As you can see in the stackblitz provided, the view of child2 does not get updated.

```
  execute(value: number): void {
    this.signal.update((data) => {
      data.property1 = value;
      data.property2 = value;
      return data;
    });
  }
```

Case #2, calling update by returning a brand new object, thus breaking the reference on the other hand does update child2.
Case #3, calling set with a brand new object also updates child2.

```
  executeSet(value: number): void {
    const data = { property1: value, property2: value };
    this.signal.update((_) => data);
    // this.signal.set(data);
  }
```

So I am wondering what is the point of using update since the behavior above is quite confusing?

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aytpoz)

Comment: Angular compares all input values as arrays and objects, similar to how JavaScript handles them by reference. In your first case, you are simply altering the properties of the same object. Since it still references the same object in memory, the signal will not be changed. Therefore, you must create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

When using `signal.update` you need to return a new reference. This is due to the signal setter discarding changes when the reference hasn't changed.

Look at the implementation of the signal setter, It will not be considered a signal update if the reference is equal:

```
export function signalSetFn<T>(node: SignalNode<T>, newValue: T) {
  if (!producerUpdatesAllowed()) {
    throwInvalidWriteToSignalError();
  }

  const value = node.value;
  if (Object.is(value, newValue)) {
    if (typeof ngDevMode !== 'undefined' && ngDevMode && !node.equal(value, newValue)) {
      console.warn(
          'Signal value equality implementations should always return `true` for' +
          ' values that are the same according to `Object.is` but returned `false` instead.');
    }
  } else if (!node.equal(value, newValue)) { // <== Here
    node.value = newValue;
    signalValueChanged(node);
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7f9ab9dc56e3422fe8ee67887ad5f3f9f54c3f36/packages/core/primitives/signals/src/signal.ts#L64-L80)

Comment: Hey @Matthieu, so why would I want to use update if the changes are being discarded? Is there a scenario in which this would make sense?

Comment: You just need to return a new instance for example using a spread operator or a library like immer.